# How do delete a file named ".." on a Linux system

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I encountered a mysterious file on my webserver today.

```
[root@hosting wwwbeta]# ls -la "mydir"
total 600
drwxr-xr-x  7 apache apache  4096 Jan  5 15:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 38 apache apache  4096 Jan  5 13:41 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root     337 Mar 25  2014 .. 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root   root    3225 Jun  6  2014 more files
```

Any ideas on how to get rid of this file? I've tried all sorts of things with rm, but it always thinks I'm referring to the directory. I'm also trying to be very careful, because this is a production server.

Comment: Use `printf '%q\n' .*` to get its *real* name, which is certainly not just `..`. That'll actually give it to you in shell-quoted form, so you can type it into the command line exactly the way that command emits it.

Comment: [BTW, questions about interactive shell usage are distinct from questions about shell programming, which are actually on-topic here; as it is, though, this should be on SuperUser or UNIX SE, not StackOverflow].

Comment: You're right. I thought I posted this on Unix, I must have gotten distracted and clicked away. Thanks. I noticed that I copied and pasted the space from my shell as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess there are spaces after the `..` Meaning the file has been created like this:

```
touch '.. '
```

You would not recognize the space using `ls`.

I would use `find` to delete the file:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '..*' -delete
```

Using `-type f` you ensure that you not attempt to remove the parent folder (which would not work anyway since it is not empty)

---

Btw, probably you should be concerned about security but the file can also been created by accident or by an erroneous script. If the file should "come back" after deletion you should be definitely concerned.

Comment: I don't know how I did not think of that. I'm not too worried about the security of the server at this point. There have been a lot of hands making hot changes in the past. I'm trying the limit that now, but there are years of cleanup.

Comment: Glad to see that it helped! :)

Answer (score 3):

Find the inode number of the file with

```
ls -ila
```

With the inode number noted, use `find`:

```
find -inum <inode> -delete
```

Comment: To be properly paranoid, that should either have a `-xdev` or a `-maxdepth 1`; otherwise, you could recurse onto a different filesystem and delete a file with the same inode number there.

Answer (score 2):

The shell itself can be asked to give you a list of filenames *in a format which can then by typed back into future shell commands successfully* with the `printf '%q'` format string. Demonstrating, with sigil characters showing start and end:

```
printf '<%q>\n' .*
```

If your directory contains a file named `..` (with a space at the end), this will emit something like:

```
<.>
<..>
<..\ >
```

...and, if copied-and-pasted without the arrow brackets, that last entry will refer to the file at hand. Alternately, if it contains, say, a tab, then it might look like:

```
<.>
<..>
<$'..\t'>
```

...and, likewise, you'll still be able to use `$'..\t'` to refer to the file in question.

Comment: Never knew about `%q`. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can see how many spaces with:

`ls -al | cat -vet`

if the file is actually named ".. " (period period space), this ought to work:

`rm "$(echo ..?)"`

If you think that there are other non-printable characters in the names, you might find `ls -q` or `ls -b` useful, too.

Comment: Why would you add an extra layer of processing to `rm ..?`? Command substitution trims trailing newlines, so there's actual bugginess potential here.

Comment: Try it yourself. just `rm ..?` will get seen as `rm ..` and just give you a warning about not being allowed to delete ..

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior -- and it doesn't make any sense that you could, either: Globs are interpreted by the shell, *before* `rm` is invoked, so the `rm` command has no way of knowing if it was passed an argument from a subcommand or from a glob expansion.

Comment: Also, `..?` doesn't match `..`; in shell glob patterns (as opposed to regular expressions), `?` isn't zero-or-one characters, it's *exactly* one character.

Comment: Bah, I'm not sure what _didn't_ work. I just re-tried and a simple `rm '.. '` or `rm ..\ ` just works.

Comment: I'm guessing it may have been a typo missing a character, ie. `rm .?`, or adding a space (`rm .. ?`).